# How to send Email using EmailComposeTask from Wp8 application in code bedind?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, email

I am trying to send email from my WP8 App using EmailComposeTask. But it is not sending the mail. Please correct the code if i am missing some statements.
My code is:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
        email.Body = "Test email from an app on click";
        email.Subject = "Testing";
        email.To = "amittal776@gmail.com";
        email.Show();


    }
```

On clicking Button , i want this mail to be send to amittal776@gmail.com. When i m running this app it asks for select an account from it will send mail after choosing it send the mail but reciever is not recieving the mail.

Comment: Code seems right to me. are you sure the email id is correct? Try checking your sent items in your email account.

Comment: yah rishabh email id is correct here.......I already checked in my send items also , it is not displaying any mail in sent box too.

Comment: code is absolutely right, try with adding cc,bcc and also put breakpoint for Debugging, may it help you out

Comment: try some other account to send your email and tell me if it works.

Comment: I added cc and bcc too but it is not showing in sent box of choosed account too

Comment: i m adding a linkedin account in settings/email+account but while selection it is not showing this account

Comment: are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: not getting any error... once i click on button ,app asks me to choose an account and choosing an account i displays the format of email and after that on clicking send. it comes back to application page.

Comment: linkedin wont show in account selection page. try adding anyone out of gmail , yahoo, hotmail, outlook account

Comment: and when you reply to anyone, you should tag him by adding @<username>. otherwise i wont get notify when you reply

Comment: Are you testing the app from the emulator?. If yes, first check you have proper Internet connection which is required to send mail. Your code is working perfectly. Also try testing in the device which has active internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in the code. EmailComposeTask is working as it should. It will always ask you to choose email account.

See this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Same happens  when you use a MediaShareTask, it will ask if you want to share on facebook/twitter/email etc etc.
This is how they are programmed in Windows phone.